# Incorrect syntax near 'ENTUserAccount'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Incorrect syntax near 'ENTUserAccount'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'ENTUserAccount'.

Source Error:

Line 76:             " WHERE " + fieldName + " = {0}" +
Line 77:             " AND " + fieldNameId + " <> {1}";
Line 78:             var result = db.ExecuteQuery(sql, new object[] { value, id });
Line 79:             List list = result.ToList();
Line 80:             return (list[0].DuplicateCount > 0);
Source File: c:\Users\ClassicSofts\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PaidTimeOffSolution\V2.PaidTimeOffDAL\Framework\ENTUserAccountData.cs    Line: 78

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'ENTUserAccount'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753346
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295154
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1325
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +1306
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +118
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +342
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters) +83
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteQuery(String query, Object[] parameters) +254
   V2.PaidTimeOffDAL.Framework.ENTUserAccountData.IsDuplicate(HRPaidTimeOffDataContext db, String tableName, String fieldName, String fieldNameId, String value, Int32 id) in c:\Users\ClassicSofts\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PaidTimeOffSolution\V2.PaidTimeOffDAL\Framework\ENTUserAccountData.cs:78
   V2.PaidTimeOffDAL.Framework.ENTUserAccountData.IsDuplicateWindowsAccountName(HRPaidTimeOffDataContext db, Int32 userAccountId, String windowsAccountName) in c:\Users\ClassicSofts\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PaidTimeOffSolution\V2.PaidTimeOffDAL\Framework\ENTUserAccountData.cs:69
   V2.PaidTimeOffBLL.Framework.ENTUserAccountEO.Validate(HRPaidTimeOffDataContext db, ENTValidationErrors& validationErrors) in c:\Users\ClassicSofts\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PaidTimeOffSolution\V2.PaidTimeOffBLL\Framework\ENTUserAccountEO.cs:66
   V2.PaidTimeOffBLL.Framework.ENTUserAccountEO.Save(HRPaidTimeOffDataContext db, ENTValidationErrors& validationErrors, Int32 userAccountId) in c:\Users\ClassicSofts\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PaidTimeOffSolution\V2.PaidTimeOffBLL\Framework\ENTUserAccountEO.cs:23
   V2.PaidTimeOffBLL.Framework.ENTBaseEO.Save(ENTValidationErrors& validationErrors, Int32 userAccountId) in c:\Users\ClassicSofts\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PaidTimeOffSolution\V2.PaidTimeOffBLL\Framework\ENTBaseEO.cs:49
   Administration_User.Master_SaveButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Program Files\IIS\PaidTimeOffUI1\Administration\User.aspx.cs:27
   PaidTimeOffEditPage.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Program Files\IIS\PaidTimeOffUI1\PaidTimeOffEditPage.master.cs:27
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553594
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Comment: is it possible to show the code that you are using instead for the `Source Error:`

Comment: The first thing to do is stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL.

Comment: (I'd also be astonished if the ASP.NET part were really relevant...)

Comment: protected static bool IsDuplicate(HRPaidTimeOffDataContext db, string tableName, string fieldName, string fieldNameId, string value, int id)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT COUNT(" + fieldNameId + ") AS DuplicateCount" +
            "FROM " + tableName +
            " WHERE " + fieldName + " = {0}" +
            " AND " + fieldNameId + " <> {1}";
            var result = db.ExecuteQuery<DuplicateCheck>(sql, new object[] { value, id });
            List<DuplicateCheck> list = result.ToList();
            return (list[0].DuplicateCount > 0);
        }